# Rails and ActionCable. Every message comes multiply times

Tags: redis, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

[image]

Env:

- Rails 5.0.5
- Redis server v=4.0.1

There is nothing special on the server side. The problem is that a user have many pings for the same message (duplicates?).

`Redis.new(url: 'redis://:auth@ip:port/db_number').pubsub('channels', 'action_cable/*')` doesn't show extra connections.

Where can be the problem? Redis? Or something wrong with the settings of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Redis server and the problem went away (it wasn't easy to do before cause the problem existed only in the production server).